# Is the "intersection" of the special Halting Problem with a language always undecidable?

Tags: turing-machines, undecidability, halting-problem, semi-decidability, decidability

I'm exploring the decidability characteristics of a particular language formed by the intersection of two languages, specifically in the context of the Halting Problem. The languages are defined as follows:

1. $\text{Special Halting Problem Language}  K: 
       K := \{ w \in \{0, 1\}^* \mid w\#w \in H \}$, where $H$ is the Halting Problem language defined as: $H := \{ w\#x \mid w, x \in \{0, 1\}^* \text{ and } M_w \text{ halts for the input } x \}$
2. Arbitrary Language $B$: A language that is not further defined for this question.

The language in question, $A$, is the intersection of these two:
$A := K \cap B$

My query pertains to the decidability status of $A$. I understand that if $B$ is undecidable, it doesn't necessarily imply that $A$ will also be undecidable, since the intersection of two undecidable languages can have different decidability properties.

Given this context, is the language $A$ decidable, semi-decidable, or undecidable? I'm looking for insights or theorems that could be applied to determine the decidability of $A$, considering the nature of $K$ and the potential characteristics of $B$.

Comment: The question is not clear. In the definition of $H$, what is $M_w$? Is $B$ arbitrary? What do you mean by "A language that is not further defined for this question"? If $B$ is the set of all words then $A = K$. If $B$ is empty, then $A = \emptyset$. The intersection can be anything, I don't see what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to clarify what is the definition of $K$ and $B$.  There seems to be some kind of typo in your definition of "Special Halting Problem", where words or symbols appear to be missing.  Please proof-read and fix the mistakes.  Please define $M_w$ and $H$.

Answer (score 1):

There is no general answer.

$B$ could be decidable or undecidable, and $A$ could too, independently of $B$. This table contains different values of $B$ for all cases.

|  | $B$ decidable | $B$ undecidable |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $A$ **decidable** ($A = \emptyset$) | $B = \emptyset$ | $B = H$ |
| $A$ **undecidable** ($A = K$) | $B = \{0, 1, \#\}^*$ | $B = K$ |